# Delete from multiple tables when the relationship is non-identifying

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

```
| User   |
|--------|
| u_id*  |
| p_id   | ← NULLABLE

| Person |
|--------|
| p_id*  |
```

In simple words:

A `User` can exist without having a related person.

The question was:

> How can I delete an user *and* its person, in the same query?

So far I have this:

```sql
DELETE `user`, `person`
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `person`
WHERE `user`.`p_id` = `person`.`p_id`
AND `u_id` = 1000
```

And it works OK for an user that is related to a person, but it doesn't delete the user if it doesn't have a related person (`p_id = NULL`).

So the question now is:

> How can I delete an user along with its person, if the user *happens* to be related to a person, in the same query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `left join` instead

```
DELETE `user`, `person`
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `person` ON `user`.`p_id` = `person`.`p_id`
WHERE `u_id` = 1000
```

Comment: Strange. Workbench was complaining about the `LEFT` join on my statement a few minutes ago, opened a new tab and it let me do the query. But it works great.

Answer (score 2):

I would add an `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your foreign key definition.  Then just delete the user and don't worry about child rows because they will be taken care of by the cascading delete.  Some links:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: I added `CASCADE` to my fk definition but the row on `person` didn't get deleted when I deleted the `user` row, I think cascading only works on `NOT NULL` fk definitions.